# How to add a semi transparent overlay to the view in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

[image]

As shown in the picture, I need similar functionality when the user touches/clicks on the EditText. When the keyboard is open , the view should be covered by a semi-transparent overlay. What is the best way to implement this?

I have my view inside a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a simple `View` as the last child in your FrameLayout and set its background to a semi-transparent color. Whenever the EditText changes focus, set the visibility of the overlay View appropriately (`View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`).

Comment: when ever I try to add a opaque image, it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Are you repeatedly adding the view each time you want the screen to dim? I meant add it once (in your layout perhaps) and only change its visibility between VISIBLE and GONE.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from **JellyBean 4.3** (API 18) you probably may do this using new `ViewOverlay` and `ViewGroupOverlay` - just add semi-transparent overlay above any parent `View` or `ViewGroup`. [Here](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.ru/2013/07/new-in-android-43-viewoverlay.html) is good introduction into this system.